# How to make fragment replaced by a specific fragment when back button pressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment, back-stack

I have an app that contain a navigation drawer one of the fragments is the home fragment I want the app when the back button pressed in some other fragments to go to the home fragment for example if the user pressed on fr1 then fr2 then fr3 I want it to return back to the home button (where fr1,2,3 are the fragments of the navigation drawer and notice that there is other fragments in the app I don't want them to go to the home when back button pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple fragments in your backstack you won't get to your home fragment just by `popBackStack()` as it just reverses one last operation. For example, it you have 3 fragments (home, fr1, fr2) first you'll get to fr2 and just then to home. If you want to get to home fragment directly onBackPress() you should replace what you currently have with your home fragment.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        int stackCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (stackCount == 1) {
            super.onBackPressed(); // if you don't have any fragments in your backstack yet.
        } else {
        // just replace container with fragment as you normally do;

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);//clear backstackfirst and then you can exit the app onbackpressed from home fr
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment());
        transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
How to check the current visible fragment

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
if (f instanceof HomeFragment) {
//do smth
}
```

Comment: My app is contain a navigation drawer which contains fragments one of this fragments is the home fragment of the app so I want when back button pressed on a  fragment this fragment replaced by the home fragment and notice that I have buttons on the fragments of the navigation drawer that go to other fragments so when this buttons pressed I don't want it to return back to the home

Comment: Well, then you just add this override method to your activity where you have drawer and fragments get replaced . It won't mess up your drawer navigation so you'll be able to go to any fragment as you do now by pressing buttons on drawer but when the user presses the back button on the device it will just then return to home

Comment: it will affect only one activity not the whole app.

Comment: This answer solved my problem but it has a small problem and I will mark it acceptable if you solved my problem when the home fragment is selected and I pressed the back button the app doesn't close how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes,you just before going to home fragment need to clear backstack and then you can exit the app, edited the answer, let me know if there's smth else

Comment: So what do you mean by your app doesn't close ? What happens? is your activity where you have drawer is the Launcher activity?

Comment: There is now a problem I have told you that I have inner  fragments rather than the navigation drawer so when I enters them and press back button it returns to the home directly and I don't want that

Comment: I knew how to solve the problem I will change the 1 in your answer to 0 and remove addToBackStack and now I need a condition to check that if the current fragment is the Home fragment or not how to do that ?

Comment: Well, it's really difficult to imagine all the transactions without seeing the actual code and app structure....added the way to check the current fragment if you feel that;s it

Comment: If you really have that load of fragments in one activity you can also check if there is a fragment of your drawer (with the edited code) then go home and if not then just use regular super.onBackPressed() if you add the other fragments to backstack

Answer (score 1):

You can override the onBackPressed() method inside your Activity, and put your Fragment transaction code inside it. I don't know exactly your operation, so below I've written a generic example you can use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question to decribe what I need exactly please tell me how to do that with explaining to the code and what does everything do