# Conditional Navigation in Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have 3 fragments A, B and C with A being the start destination of my nav graph. When the user starts the app, I check in fragment A if there are previously stored results. If there are, I want to navigate straight to fragment C. I have managed to get this to work. However, when the user presses back in fragment C in this case, I want them to be taken to fragment B instead of A, and that's what I need help figuring out.

[image]

**Note:** Fragment A is just a setup fragment which is only visited once when the app starts. Which means when the user presses back from fragment B, they are taken to OS home screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onBackPress()` and replace whatever fragment you are in with FragmentB like this

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int stackCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (stackCount == 1) {
        super.onBackPressed(); // if you don't have any fragments in your backstack yet.
    } else {
    // just replace container with fragment as you normally do;

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);//clear backstackfirst and then you can exit the app onbackpressed from home fr
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentB());
    transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

This is the original answer ,you can take a look [answer by Rainmaker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505744/7940639)

Answer (score 0):

You can override your onBackPressed  on fragment C and call your navController to go back to fragment b creating a new action from C to B

```
navController.navigate(R.id.action_CFragment_to_BFragment)
```